# How to write in file at specific location?

Tags: c, file

I have a homework assignment and we must use .txt files.

Here's my file example:

1 John 1234 558 
2 Myke 2222 9876 
...

I want to overwrite the 558 number in the file. The ID (1,2...) are given. I've been searching around and the fopen() function only provides arguments for beginning and appending.

Comment: What number do you want to write? Same length as 558 (3 digits) or maybe different length?

Comment: Maybe different length.

Comment: Solved it with the `rewrite everything` method. The function is here: http://pastebin.com/zbPpXsz9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually easier to re-write the file in its entirety. You must have a reading and a writing function already. So you read, the modify your in-memory data structures, then you write everything out again.

Comment: Done this. Here is the function, if anyone is interested. http://pastebin.com/zbPpXsz9

Answer (score 6):

You can use the fopen("filename", "r+b") to open a file for updating (in binary mode).
You can then use fseek to set were you want to write next and use fwrite/fputs or similar to update the data.

For example, say you start with a file *test.text* which looks like this

```
0123456789abcde
0123456789abcde
0123456789abcde
```

you can use the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *f;
  if(!(f = fopen("./test.text", "r+b"))) //open the file for updating
    return -1;
  fseek(f, 16, SEEK_SET);//set the stream pointer 16 bytes from the start.
  const char message[] = "Hello, World!";
  fputs(message,f);
  return 0;
}
```

and the result would be

```
0123456789abcde
Hello, World!de
0123456789abcde
```

you will still need to first search the file for the id you want to replace, and you may run into problems when you want to replace "558" with "12345" unless there are extra spaces on the line to pad the output. As you will start overwriting data from the next line.

Answer (score 2):

fopen to open the file, then [seek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to the right bit, then write the appropriate bits, taking great care not to overwrite anything further in the file you didn't want to overwrite!

If you need to insert more data than was taken up by the existing text then you'll have to re-append the rest of the file contents from that point.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions to seek to a given position in a file, but this position is a byte offset in the file. You do not know the offset in advance, so you will need to read the file line per line until you discover the line with the given ID. Then you can skip the name, the first number and you are at the 558. The problem now is that you can overwrite the 558 in the file, but you cannot write 12 and delete the 8 from 558. You also cannot replace the 558 with a 1234 because you would overwrite the 558 with 123 and would need to insert the 4.

One simple solution would be to work with a second file. You could read file 1 line per line and copy each line to file 2. Despite the line with the given ID. You would modify that line before writing it to file 2.

If you know how to do it, you could also work with a big buffer and do the replacement in file 1 without the need for a second file.

If you are allowed to work with two files, you should do that. If the files are short and you are allowed to read the complete file into memory, you could read the file, do the modification in memory and write back the file.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming your .txt file consists of the above mentioned 4 fields) You can have two FILE pointers one with read permissions and the other with write permission. Suppose your file is named xyz.txt, let fp_read with read access point to it, where let fp_write point to a new file xyz_bkp.txt.

**Variables**:
char *curr_line, *name;
int id, second_num, third_num;

The trick here is to read the file xyz.txt line by line into a string(say curr_line)
Then read the values in the line into different variables using sscanf. Eg-
sscanf(curr_line, "%d %s %d %d", &id, name, &second_num, &third_num);

Now based on values of the variables, either write the values to the xyz_bkp.txt file unconditionally or change them as per your will.

**NOTE**: After you are done, you would need to **delete the original xyz.txt** and **rename xyz_bkp.txt to xyz.txt**(simple enough)